# i want to delete the entire row, In sheet 2, if column D has INACTIVE and column H has #N/A like as below.can anyone help for that code?

Tags: excel, vba

like the highlighted cell, in sheet 2,if D contains inactive and H contains #N/A delete that entirw row.

[image]

Comment: Please show your code and mark the problem's line maybe

Answer (score 0):

See a sample code below. This is based on the data that you provided in your image. Note the comments:

```
Sub DeleteRow()

Dim rngRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 'Count the number of rows that have data

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 'Use this reverse loop so that it will delete the rows from the bottom up to prevent a bad job!

    If Cells(i, 4).Value = "INACTIVE" And IsError(Cells(i, 8).Value) Then 'If 4th column is INACTIVE and 8th column is an error from a formula

    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete ' delete the rows!

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    'Set the sheet you want to delete
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        'Find the last row of column A
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop from lastrow up to row 2 and delete if conditions met
        For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1

            If .Range("D" & i).Value = "INACTIVE" And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(.Range("H" & i).Value) Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```